# ubuntu cannot find /usr/bin/ld -lperl

Tags: perl

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

command used

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/per;/5.30/Core -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt libtool
```

On the above path I see these files related to perl

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30/CORE$ ls -l | grep perl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48759 Oct  5 10:27 iperlsys.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  270175 Oct  5 10:27 perl.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6223 Oct  5 10:27 perl_inc_macro.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2914 Oct  5 10:27 perl_langinfo.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10170 Oct  5 10:27 perlapi.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9464 Oct  5 10:27 perlio.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13761 Oct  5 10:27 perliol.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     527 Oct  5 10:27 perlsdio.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13314 Oct  5 10:27 perlvars.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4434 Oct  5 10:27 perly.h
```

Please advice which perl is missing and how to fix it

Comment: You used `per;` instead of `perl` in the command.

Answer (score 1):

The message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl` means that `ld` cannot find the shared object file `libperl.so` which is provided by the `libperl-dev` package:

```
$ apt-file list libperl-dev
libperl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.a
libperl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so
libperl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/cross-config
libperl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libperl-dev/README.cross
libperl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libperl-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libperl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libperl-dev/copyright
libperl-dev: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libperl-dev
```

Since it is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (which is in the gcc compiler's default library search path for the x86_64 target) you should not need to supply additional `-L` arguments.